# Deleting Everything except Strings that Contain Certain Phrases

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of many email addresses. Formatted similarly as follows:

```
Business Name 01    email01@business01.com; email02@business01.com; email03@business01.com; email04@business01.com; email05@business01.com;
Business Name 02    email01@business02.com; email02@business02.com; email03@business02.com; email04@business02.com; email05@business02.com;
Business Name 03    email01@business03.com; email02@business03.com; email03@business03.com; email04@business03.com; email05@business03.com;
```

I am looking to delete everything except emails that begin with 'email02' and 'email04'. So the list should look like:

```
Business Name 01    email02@business01.com; email04@business01.com;
Business Name 02    email02@business02.com; email04@business02.com;
Business Name 03    email02@business03.com; email04@business03.com;
```

Struggling with this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\h)(?!email0[24])\S+@\S+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\h)             # positive lookbehind, make sure we have space before
(?!email0[24])      # negative lookahead, make sure we aven't email02 or email04 after
\S+                 # 1 or more on space
@                   # @
\S+                 # 1 or more on space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: works great. marked as answer. However, I realised my problem is a little more complex, so I made a new question, that has different requirements.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020996/cleaning-a-list-of-strings-and-keeping-only-certain-content - I will leave this question here anyway, since it might be of use to someone.

Comment: @kylie2675647: For the other question just replace `(?<=\h)(?!email0[24])\S+@\S+` by `(?<=\h)(?!info|contact)\S+@\S+`. You can delete other question.

Comment: Someone has made a javascript solution too. I think it could be useful for others. I will use yours!