# Cleaning a list of Strings and Keeping only Certain Content

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of many email addresses. Formatted similarly as follows. You will notice that each "business" has similar email addresses that begin the same way.

```
Business Name 01    email@business01.com; info@business01.com; admin@business01.com; other@business01.com; contact@business01.com;`enter code here`
Business Name 02    email@business02.com; info@business02.com; admin@business02.com; other@business02.com; contact@business02.com;
Business Name 03    email@business03.com; info@business03.com; admin@business03.com; other@business03.com; contact@business03.com;
```

I am looking to delete everything except emails that begin with 'info' and 'contact'. So the final list should look like:

```
Business Name 01    info@business01.com; contact@business01.com;
Business Name 02    info@business02.com; contact@business02.com;
Business Name 03    info@business03.com; contact@business03.com;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible with just notepad++, but with a bit of JavaScript you can work on each business separately, then filter to keep only the email addresses you want, then reformat them.

```js
const data = `Business Name 01    email@business01.com; info@business01.com; admin@business01.com; other@business01.com; contact@business01.com;
Business Name 02    email@business02.com; info@business02.com; admin@business02.com; other@business02.com; contact@business02.com;
Business Name 03    email@business03.com; info@business03.com; admin@business03.com; other@business03.com; contact@business03.com;`

const output = data.split("\n")
  .map((business) => {
    const [name, emails] = business.split("    ");
    const newEmails = emails.slice(0, -1).split("; ").filter((email) => email.startsWith("info") || email.startsWith("contact"));
    return `${name}    ${newEmails.join("; ")};`;
  })
  .join("\n");
  
console.log(output);
a.innerText = output;
```

```html
<pre id=a></pre>
```

Here's a version where you can click a button and it should get all the data from your clipboard.

```js
async function everything() {
  const data = await navigator.clipboard.readText();

  const output = data.split("\n")
    .map((business) => {
      const [name, emails] = business.split("    ");
      const newEmails = emails.slice(0, -1).split("; ").filter((email) => email.startsWith("info") || email.startsWith("contact"));
      return `${name}    ${newEmails.join("; ")};`;
    })
    .join("\n");

  await navigator.clipboard.writeText(output);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="everything()">click me</button>
```

Comment: ok. maybe there's a couple of issues: 1. i have like 9K business names. I guess I can do it in batches. 2. I don't really know how to run javascript, I only know it from using it on webpages etc.

Comment: @kylie2675647 I've added a version where you can copy all of the data to your clipboard (the text of the file, not the file itself) and it will output the new version to the clipboard which you can then paste.

Comment: Why using javascript when Notepad++ does the job pretty well?

Comment: @Toto read the first line of the answer; also i was unaware that the OP asked the exact same question a few hours ago

Comment: That doesn't explain why using javascript. Have you seen the dupicate?

Comment: It's not exactly the same, by the way.

Comment: @Toto I used javascript because that's what I know how to do, it runs easily on this site (no need to find another website to run the code), and didn't know the OP asked the same question already